# How do I perform a nightly production to test database copy between Azure SQL Servers

Tags: azure-sql-database

We’re trying to migrate to Azure SQL, and have built a prod and test SQL server (using Azure Devops, Bicep and Powershell). We have a requirement for a manual process in an Azure Devops pipeline (this needs to be manual as we need a steady state in test when getting ready for a release) to copy the prod databases over the top of the test ones when we need to refresh the data. As the prod databases may not be consistent in the day, when this is triggered, the database we want to restore is as at 4am this morning.

We originally attempted this with a nightly pipeline that ran New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy to copy the prod databases to a serverless backup copy (I couldn’t use the elastic pool the test databases are sat in, as its at the limit of the number of databases it can hold) on the test server, we could then drop the test database and do a create as copy of to create the test database as needed. This worked really nicely in performance but resulted in us running up a massive bill (think six times the bill for the whole company), we’re still trying to understand why that is with the support team, but I suspect it’s to do with the interplay of the retention period of Azure deleted databases, and us doing a delete and restore every night.

Ideally, I’d like to do a restore from a point in time of the prod database, over the top of the existing database on the test server, but combinations of New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy and Restore-AzSqlDatabase don’t seem to be able to get me there. I’d also need to be sure that this approach wouldn’t slow down the prod databases or cost an excessive amount, and would be reasonably performant.

I’d be comfortable with detaching the backup from the restore, and running the backup step early every morning as a fallback, again as long as it didn’t cost an excessive amount.

In terms of speed, I’m not too fussed about how long the backup step costs as long as it’s detached from the restore, but ideally the restore step needs to be efficient as possible, as it puts our test instance out of action for the time it runs for.

Has anyone got to such a solution that works effectively and efficiently, any help greatfully recieved!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of is the honest answer! We never worked out a way of doing it across two servers and Microsoft support ended up saying they didn't think it was feasible, but we got to a nice compromise.

We created a single server for both sets of databases, but placed them in two elastic pools. As the server is just a logical arrangement and the thing we wanted to protect against was overwhelming of compute, the elastic pools ring fenced the live compute nicely.

We could then do point in time restores from live into test using powershell to restore live from last night without the need to backup. This approach does mean that secrets are shared between the two, but it covered off our needs well.